# mysql query optimiser better performance from subquery with partitions than left join with index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, partitioning, myisam

when using mysql version 5.6.14-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log on an ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I encounter the following behaviour when querying data from these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
          `id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
          `request_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
        !50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(request_time))
        (PARTITION p15062116 VALUES LESS THAN (1434895200) ENGINE = MyISAM,
         PARTITION p15062117 VALUES LESS THAN (1434898800) ENGINE = MyISAM,
         PARTITION p15062118 VALUES LESS THAN (1434902400) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        ...
        PARTITION rest VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM)

CREATE TABLE `b` (
          `id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          `item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `item2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`start_time`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
        !50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))
        (PARTITION p15062516 VALUES LESS THAN (1435240800) ENGINE = MyISAM,
         PARTITION p15062517 VALUES LESS THAN (1435244400) ENGINE = MyISAM
        ....
        PARTITION rest VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM)
```

using this query results in a 1 second runtime:

```
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE request_time, item  
    FROM a left join
      (select * 
       from b 
       where start_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00'
      ) c using(id) 
where request_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00'
```

explain output:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 336972 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 152     | func |     10 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | b  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |  39508 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain partitions SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE request_time, item  FROM a  left join (select * from b where start_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00') b using(id) where request_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:
+----+-------------+------------+---------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions          | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+---------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a   | p15062810,p15062811 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 336972 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL                | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 152     | func |     10 | Using where |
|  2 | DERIVED     | b  | p15062810,p15062811 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |  39508 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+---------------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

and using this query results in 30 seconds runtime:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE request_time, item
FROM a
left join b using(id)
where request_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00' 
and (start_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00' or start time is null) ;
```

explain output:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 336972 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 152     | func |    395 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
mysql> explain partitions SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE request_time, item  FROM a  left join b using(id) where request_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00' and start_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions          | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a  | p15062810,p15062811 | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 336972 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b | p15062810,p15062811 | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 152     | func |    395 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
```

I expected similar or better results from the second query based on the usage of the id index and the 1 hour partition.
both tables have 1000000~ records each.

can you explain why is the first query much more efficient than the second one?

can we refactor the first query so that it might become a view or a reusable query instead of rebuilding the subquery for each join?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the optimizer can do partition elimination for this expression `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(request_time)`? Btw, both queries return totally different results. Q1 is the same as a simple COUNT(*) without any join while Q2 is the same as an Inner Join.

Comment: Yes it can do partition elimination based on that, it works in every other scenario. You are correct about the query it's the wrong one. I'll fix it.

Comment: You're "optimizing" using MyISAM storage. It's just silly. All of your queries and tests only measure how good the OS is scheduling the hard drive reads. MyISAM is outdated engine, at least use InnoDB and start optimizing once you swap the storage. You can fine-tune it better for quicker results. 1m records equals **nothing** and with InnoDB you can at least control how much data fits into RAM, thus you can avoid disk seeks all together.

Comment: Myisam is a must, this is a product limitation currently.

Comment: Are there really no indexes in `a`???

Comment: Not fair -- you include `request_time` in one query but not the other.

Comment: Readers please note `<auto_key0>` -- This is a new feature in 5.6 that probably greatly improved the first formulation.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...` so we can see if it is doing pruning.

Comment: no indexes in a, the code tag wasnt around all the query so you missed it, fixed it and addd the explain partitions.

Comment: There are 0 reasons you MUST use MyISAM. I don't know who your boss or clients are, but if you're an expert and if you are optimizing something - do it **right**. It's super stupid to have a square "wheel" on a car and to try optimize it's road friction. It's also stupid to use an engine that won't let you do what you want, if you are only 1 simple command away from swapping the engine. MyISAM doesn't do anything that InnoDB isn't doing, save a silly feature with auto incrementing a primary key when it's composite.

Comment: We intend  to migrate to innodb/another db later in the cycle, currently this is a limitation.

Comment: `between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00'` include two :00:00.  Hence two partitions are needed !

Comment: I still see no index for `a`.  It possibly needs `PRIMARY KEY(id, request_time)`.

Comment: adding the index did not change runtime.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that SQL engine is having a hard time determining the partitions for the second query.  You might try writing it as:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(*)
FROM a left join
     b
     using(id)
where request_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00' and
      start_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and  '2015-06-28 11:00:00'
UNION ALL
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(*)
FROM a left join
     b
     using (id)
WHERE request_time between '2015-06-28 10:00:00' and '2015-06-28 11:00:00' and
      start time is null ;
```

I realize this returns two rows.  It is easy enough to add the values together, if this helps the engine find the right partitions.

Comment: Actually the count(*) is just an example, the real live scenrio involves actual data from both tables.

Comment: @YoniAllon . . . The question is whether breaking this into two subqueries makes the query faster.  Bringing the data together afterwards is pretty simple, whatever the operations are.